# Loop posts only excluding first post

Tags: loop, query

On the main blog page for a site I am developing, my designer has the first post styled uniquely and in a different section on the page than the rest. Since it is a paginated archive page, I need to loop through all posts on the paginated page just excluding the first post, as I will get that in it's own loop.

I tried the Offset option within the query, but learned that that kills pagination which won't work.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: did you check out https://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination?

Comment: You can just skip the first one in the loop...

Answer (score 3):

You don't need separate queries, you can run multiple loops on the same query-

```
// output first post
if( have_posts() ){
    the_post();
    the_title();
}

// output the rest of the posts...
if( have_posts() ){
    while( have_posts() ){
        the_post();
        the_title();
    }
}
```

You can also use `rewind_posts()` to reset the current post back to 0, as well as manually set `$wp_query->current_post` to whatever index you want and start the loop there (note: the post counter starts at 0, not 1).

If you only want to style the first post on the first page and not subsequent pages, you can check if it's **not** paged with `! is_paged()`

```
if( ! is_paged() ){
    echo 'this will only output on the first page';
    if( have_posts() ){
        the_post();
        the_title();
    }
}
```

Comment: the above suggestion is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Following this step:

Step 1: For different section you can display first Posts. when put this code.

```
<?php
// For your frist post
global $post,$firstPosts;
$args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'orderby' => 'post_date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
        );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        $firstPosts[] = $post->ID;
        echo get_the_title();  
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Step 2: On your blog page listing. Put this code in **Index.php** file. for Loop posts only excluding first post

```
<?php
// blog page
// Put this code after get_header(); line

global $wp_query,$firstPosts;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query,  array( 'post__not_in' => $firstPosts ) );
query_posts( $args ); 

?>
```